# Regular expression for Less or more than 9 digits Repeating digits for first 5 or all 9 digits and only number?

Tags: regex, echosign

I have this

```
"^(?!(11111|22222|33333|44444|55555|66666|77777|88888|99999|00000))([0-9]\d{8})"
```

regular expression in c# code and javascript works fine but in text tag of adobe echosign doesnt works anyone have anotherway to work on texttag of echosign?

Comment: Maybe echosign doesn't have symbol classes?

Comment: Try to use [0-9] instead of \d.

Comment: thank you and for the length of the string? for example 123456789 ok   bad 1234567890 make sense?

Comment: I don't understand your question, and your title even less. Could you clarify please?

Comment: anyone have a regex for validate max lenght 9 in the string?

Answer (score 2):

By your last comment, you need a regex to validate a string of maximum length 9 containing digits only:

```
^[0-9]{1,9}$
```

This will validate any string containing digits, with length at least 1 and not greater than 9.

If you want to avoid strings such as `098` (leading zeroes), use this instead:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,8}$
```

EDIT: If I understand your question well now, you can use this regex:

```
^(?!([0-9])\1\1-\1\1)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$
```

That is assuming that echosign can handle callbacks, if not, you can use this instead:

```
^(?!(?:111-11|222-22|333-33|444-44|555-55|666-66|777-77|888-88|999-99|000-00))[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: i have this regex 

for repeating less or more than 9 digit on the string and for first 5 digit and all 9 digit     

^(?!(11111|22222|33333|44444|55555|66666|77777|88888|99999|00000))([0-9]{9})$

and the regex for ssn format ###-##-#### 

^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$

how can work on echosign validating with out ssn format 123456789 or with ssn format?

Comment: @FernandoXD What does `less or more than 9 digit` mean? And what does `for first 5 digit and all 9 digit` mean!? They just don't make any sense to me!

Comment: hi have this regex ^(?!(11111|22222|33333|44444|55555|66666|77777|88888|99999|00000))([0-9]{9})$ how can combine this regex with ssn format regex xxx-xx-xxxx in another words validate by 2 ways?

Comment: @FernandoXD How do the two last regexes do for you? (I edited my answer)